# AngularJS chosen plugin, chosen:updated not working, works in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, jquery-chosen

I have integrated the chosen plugin into my angularjs app. My app.js looks like this.

```
myApp.directive('chosen', function() {

    var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch('countriesList', function() {
            $('#countries').trigger('chosen:updated');
            console.log('I acctuallty get in here');
        })
        element.chosen();
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker
    };
})
```

my select looks like this

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label for ="countries" class="control-label">Countries: </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select chosen ng-model="countries" id="countries" ng-options="country.name for country in countriesList"  data-placeholder="Select Countries" multiple class="span chzn-select"></select>  
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when the page first loads nothing is displayed in the select. The options are there when you inspect element.

The `chosen:updated` just doesn't seem to work. I put the `console.log()` in the watch and it is firing. If I run the `.trigger('chosen:updated')` in the browser it works perfectly. I did try `element.trigger` but that did not work either. So Frustrating!

Comment: Does `console.log` inside of your `$watch` fire every time you make changes? Or does it fire only once?

Comment: it fires the first time i load the page.

Comment: You add an item to `countriesList`, but it does not update?

Comment: No when I load the page there is nothing in the drop down

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to let Angular (well the browser actually) render the select properly before calling `chosen`. You can do this by using `setTimeout` or Angular's `$timeout`.

```
app.directive('chosen', function($timeout) {

  var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {

    $timeout(function () {
      element.chosen();
    }, 0, false);
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linker
  };
});
```

The third argument `false` prevents an unnecessary digest loop.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/9Afq65uatTjnb4J6ICcB?p=preview

If you need to add or remove items dynamically this will work:

```
app.directive('chosen', function($timeout) {

  var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {

    scope.$watch('countriesList', function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        element.trigger('chosen:updated');
      }, 0, false);
    }, true);

    $timeout(function() {
      element.chosen();
    }, 0, false);
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linker
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/rEBu6d3HtaNhThWidB5h?p=preview

Note that by default `$watch` uses reference equality to determine if to execute the listener or not. If you add an item to the array the variable `countriesList` will still refer to the same array, so the listener will not execute.

The third argument `true` passed to `$watch` makes it use `angular.equals` instead of reference equality.

Comment: Thanks Tasse, this worked great once I found out that Angular needs to be included AFTER jQuery :-)

Comment: Thanks, its really help me.